# Re-Apply Linq to entities from last Iqueryable

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

here my issue:

I've an `IQueryable` object and I need to execute a new query on Db (just like a refresh) by launching the same contained query in my `IQueryable` obj. 
An example:

```
myObj = objCtx.Person
    .Where(p => p.IdPerson...)
    .OrderBy(p => ...)
    .Select(..some field..);
//...
// From another function I just want re-execute 
// the same query
// -> Well, that retrieve full lambda 
var et = this.myObj.Expression
// This doesn't work:
var anotherObj = objCtx.Person.Where(et); 
//or..
var tmp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(et);
// This doesn't work too:
var anotherObj = objCtx.Person.Where(tmp);
```

Is it possibile to achieve? What am I missing?

Thanks

Ok:
I would be able to retrieve full query (select statement) from an IQueryable object and execute it in order to get all my updated data.

This is the original query:

```
this.myIQueryableObj = objCtx.Person
        .Where(p => p.IdPerson...)
        .OrderBy(p => ...)
        .Select(..some field..);

//..And in some button click, I want execute again the above query, but all what I know is myIQueryableObjOnly. Can you help me?
```

Comment: I think the reason your questions don't get answered is because they are consistently of low quality. Try writing better questions.